# Automatic email sending with timer control

Tags: c#, winforms, email, date, timer

I need to create an auto email sender system, C#, that needs to read data from one database. That data is, mostly, a datetime and an ID.
For each date I'll need to calculate the diff between the date inserted and the current date of the system.
I've already wrote pieces of code, to send mail:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
 var fromAddress = new MailAddress("xxx@gmail.com", "NAME1");
 var toAddress = new MailAddress("aaa@gmail.com", "To Name");
 const string fromPassword = "pass";
 const string subject = "TEST";
 const string body = "WARNING";
 var smtp = new SmtpClient
  {
   Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
   Port = 587,
   EnableSsl = true,
   DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
   UseDefaultCredentials = false,
   Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
  };
 using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
 {
  Subject = subject,
  Body = body
  })
  {
  smtp.Send(message);
  }
 }
```

I need to control this with a timer and everytime the application is started, but only if there are dates coming to the limit.

In the form load I read all the dates and the person who needs to be informed with this email about the ending of the date. I do that with:

```
string constring4 = Classe_Ligacao.cn;
string Query4 = "select DATE,IDPerson from Diligencia Where DATE IS NOT NULL";
SqlConnection cn4 = new SqlConnection(constring4);
SqlCommand cmd4 = new SqlCommand(Query4, cn4); 
try
{
 cn4.Open();
 using (SqlDataReader read4 = cmd4.ExecuteReader())
 {
  while (read4.Read())
  {
   string pr = (read4["DATE"].ToString());
   string ida = (read4["IDPerson"].ToString());

   string constring2 = Classe_Ligacao.cn;
   string query2 = "select name,Email  FROM Person WHERE IDPerson='" + ida + "'";
   SqlConnection cn2 = new SqlConnection(constring2); 
   SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query2, cn2);
   cn2.Open();
   using (SqlDataReader read2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader())
   {
     while (read2.Read())
     {
      string ab = (read2["Name"].ToString());
      string ema = (read2["Email"].ToString());
      MessageBox.Show(ab, ema);
     }
    }
   cn2.Close();
  }
 }
}
finally
{
cn4.Close();
}
```

I need to associate the email read to send, the date and the days left until the end of the date. How can I do that, associating all to a timer?

Hope you can understand my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic concept is very easy to implement: in a loop, subtract the current time from the time of the next operation (i.e. when you next need to send email), and then wait for that length of time.

For example:

```
static async Task ProcessSchedule(IEnumerable<DateTime> schedule)
{
    // Release caller
    await Task.Yield();

    // Process the queue
    foreach (DateTime eventTime in schedule)
    {
        TimeSpan nextEvent = eventTime - DateTime.UtcNow;

        Console.Write(
            "waiting {0:0.000} seconds...", Math.Max(0, nextEvent.TotalSeconds));
        if (nextEvent.Ticks > 0)
        {
            await Task.Delay(nextEvent);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(eventTime);
    }
}
```

When I call the above like this:

```
// Setup
double[] futureSeconds = { 1, 2.5, 3.7, 5, 9, 12.2, 15 };
BlockingCollection<DateTime> queue = new BlockingCollection<DateTime>();
Task task = ProcessSchedule(queue.GetConsumingEnumerable());

// This would be equivalent to whatever process you have generating
// the DateTime-based events (e.g. reading from a database)
DateTime startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
foreach (DateTime eventTime in futureSeconds.Select(s => startTime + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(s)))
{
    queue.Add(eventTime);
}

// Don't call this until you want processing to stop
queue.CompleteAdding();

task.Wait();
```

I get the following output:

> waiting 1.000 seconds...12/5/2014 7:35:43 PM
>   waiting 1.469 seconds...12/5/2014 7:35:45 PM
>   waiting 1.184 seconds...12/5/2014 7:35:46 PM
>   waiting 1.297 seconds...12/5/2014 7:35:47 PM
>   waiting 3.984 seconds...12/5/2014 7:35:51 PM
>   waiting 3.184 seconds...12/5/2014 7:35:54 PM
>   waiting 2.797 seconds...12/5/2014 7:35:57 PM

Note that each delay is not quite the full amount you'd expect from the initialized seconds. I.e. while the second event is occurs 2.5 seconds after the start time, there's only a 1.469 second delay. This is because the technique automatically accounts for the time spent processing the previous event before it gets to the point of waiting again.

Of course, in the above you would replace your queue type with whatever object you have that contains the particulars, like the `DateTime` of the user's next email notice along with of course their particulars for emailing them. The `ProcessSchedule()` method would contain the logic to actually send the email. The code to add things to the queue would instead be whatever logic you have for pulling the information from the database, where you of course add the limit you mentioned to the base date in the database to determine when the actual expiration time would be.

The above all assumes that your general state is relatively unchanging. It can easily deal with adding new events that will occur later than any other event already queued. For anything more sophisticated, such as handling a scenario where a user's base time is updated before their event has expired, or adding a new user with a base time earlier than the most recent already queued, some changes would need to be made in the underlying queue and processing.

The exact details of that depend a lot on what you actually need to do. Hopefully the above gives you a good enough push in the right direction that you can refine to suit your specific needs, but of course if you have trouble adapting this, feel free to ask another question.

Comment: Maybe missing an `if (nextEvent.Ticks > 0)` before the `Task.Delay()`

Comment: good point...I was trying to keep things simple, but that probably oversimplifies too much. I'll update.