# How to manage a collection of thread safe tasks

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm working on a service that gets a list of tasks from an API. It gets a list of tasks and each of which has an SQL query and the frequency that query needs to be run at.

## Current implemention

```
BlockingCollection<QueryRunner> queue = new BlockingCollection<QueryRunner> ();
// Get the list of tasks from an API and serialize them as a Query object.
List<Query> queries = new List<Query>();
dynamic result = _unitOfWork.Get(string.Format("branches/{0}/queries", selectedBranch.id)).Result["queries"];
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
queries = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Query>>(json, _serializerSettings);

// Query is an object that has an id, a frequency and the SQL text for the
// query.
// QueryRunner is the object that holds the query object and a time
// reference.
foreach (Query query in queries)
{
    QueryRunner queryRunner = new QueryRunner()
    {
        Query = query,
        Branch = _selectedBranch
    };
    queue.Add(queryRunner);
}
queue.CompleteAdding();

// Start processing the queue.
var background = Task.Factory.StartNew(ProcessQueries);

// ProcessQueries body:
int taskCount = 4;
var actions = Enumerable.Repeat<Action> (ProcessQueue, taskCount);
Parallel.Invoke (actions.ToArray ());

// ProcessQueue body:
foreach (QueryRunner queryRunner in _queue.GetConsumingEnumerable()) {
    Query query = queryRunner.Query;
    TimerCallback timerDelegate = new TimerCallback (RunQuery);
    TimeSpan timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds (query.frequency);
    Timer timer = new Timer (timerDelegate, queryRunner, 0, (int)timeSpan.TotalMilliseconds);
    queryRunner.TimerReference = timer;
}
```

And finally, **RunQuery** just executes the SQL text and send the results back to the API.

```
QueryRunner queryRunner = (QueryRunner)queryObj;
if (!queryRunner.IsWorking)
{
    queryRunner.IsWorking = true;
    // Open connection, run query, get results and send them back to the
    // API.
    queryRunner.IsWorking = false;
}
```

## The problem

Not exactly a problem, but now I need to mantain that queue.

The service must ask for tasks back again to the API in a period of time.

The new set of tasks may or may not contain the same queries or change the frequency or the existing ones.

I see that BlockingCollection does not expose methods to remove or update specific items in the collection, so what would be a better approach?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Generally: you simply need to set up a queue, ordered by the time a given operation is supposed to occur. Then use a timer, `await Task.Delay()`, etc. to process the next event in the queue at the right time (i.e. subtract the current time from the next event time and wait that long). See my answer to a related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27598564/3538012  In that example, the time of events is picked randomly (i.e. no queue), but the basic idea is the same.

Comment: Actually, this related question is probably more on-the-nose in terms of relevance: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27323846/3538012  Your question might even be considered a duplicate of that one

Comment: Excelent! I'll check those answers.